# Hardhat TypeError: etherWallet.ownerAddress is not a function

Tags: javascript, typeerror, solidity, smartcontracts, hardhat

Im making a simple ether wallet smart contract. When i try to deploy the contract with deploy script in hardhat, im getting this error. Following is my deploy.js code

```
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
  const etherWalletFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("wallet");
  console.log("Deploying, Please wait...");
  const etherWallet = etherWalletFactory.deploy();
  (await etherWallet).waitForDeployment();
  console.log("Contract Deployed");
  console.log(`Contract address: ${etherWallet.address}`);
  const owner = await etherWallet.ownerAddress();
  console.log(owner);
  const balance = await etherWallet.getBalance();
  console.log(`Current Balance: ${balance}`);
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

And this is my Solidity code (wallet.sol) :

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

contract wallet {
    address payable private owner;

    constructor() {
        owner = payable(msg.sender);
    }

    receive() external payable {}

    function ownerAddress() public view returns (address) {
        return owner;
    }

    function getBalance() public view returns (uint) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }

    function sendEth(uint _amount, address payable _recipient) public payable {
        require(_amount < address(this).balance, "Insufficient funds");
        _recipient.transfer(_amount);
    }

    function withdraw(uint _amount) public {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "You are not the owner");
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(_amount);
    }
}
```

This is the error im getting on running deploy.js

```
Contract Deployed
Contract address: undefined
TypeError: etherWallet.ownerAddress is not a function
    at main (/home/yash/Codes/ether-wallet/scripts/deploy.js:10:35)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Im using `yarn hardhat run scripts/deploy.js` command to run the script

I tried deleting artifacts and cache files manually and by using `yarn hardhat clean` command multiple times but im still getting this error.